# Migration of a 'resourceManager' from ES5 to ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am currently trying to migrate a project that uses a resourceManager.
I tried to sketch the functionality in the picture below. It basicly made it easier to use the different services I needed.
[image: ES5 resourceManager]

Now tried to migrate this to ES6 but as it is only possible to import either default or named exports.
Is there a way, so I don't have to import every single function of e.g logger or atleast do that just once inside `resourceManager.js` and export them 'bundled' as logger?
Something like this:

```js
import {debug, error, info} as loggerFunctions from './logger.js'
export loggerFunctions as logger
```

So it is possible to do the following in every module using the resourceManager:

```js
import {logger} from './resourceManager.js'
logger.debug('My debug log')
logger.error('Thats an error')
...
```

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: This looks a bit like a [barrel file](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/barrel), though with an extra level of module objects. I'd rather avoid this within a package (it can be fine as the public interface of your package though). Why not just write `import logger from './logger'; import config from './config';`? It's one line shorter!

Comment: actually I didn't come up with the idea. It is exactly what you pointed out as 'barrel file'. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-export all exports like this:

```
export * as logger from './logger.js'
```

[MDN has a nice overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) over all the valid ways to use `export`.